How to receive a sequence of serial data with variable length efficiently
I have a method to receive a sequence of serial data message in a while loop. Each of them could be more than 100 bytes but less than 2048 bytes. Most of them are about 1000 bytes.
public int RecvSerialData(ref byte[] respBuf, int delay)
{
    var recvBuf = new byte[2048];
    var count = m_serial.BytesToRead;
    if (count > 0)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Restart();
        while (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < delay)
        {
        }

        count = m_serial.BytesToRead;
        m_serial.Read(recvBuf, 0, count);
        
        // Do something with respBuf
        return count;
    }
    return -1;
}

The problem is I don't know the exact length of each message since the communication protocol does not contain it.
So when I transfer a delay to this method, it would waste a large of time if the delay is too long. But if the delay is too short, the message would not receive completely which would cause an issue.
Is there some better method to receive variable length serial data?

The client would not send next message until I reply the message before, so there is no risk to receive the next message even if I transfer a very long delay here.
As a matter of fact, I spent over 65 seconds to receive all of those serial messages if I transfer delay of 30ms, and all messages are received completely.
And spent less than 20 seconds if I transfer delay of 5ms, but some messages are not received completely and caused some issues.
My project is a Winform project with .NET Framework 4.6.

Protocol:

Host(1 byte, fixed 0x02)
Step(1 byte, fixed 0x35 at this moment)
InfoA(1 byte)
InfoB(2 bytes)
ACK/NAK(1 byte)
Error Code(4 bytes)
InfoC(2 bytes)
Body(0-2000 bytes)

Info areas are used for transfer some info of client, similar to Host and Step. There are no length or crc in Info areas.
Edit:
Thanks for all. I found a better way. Not perfect, but good enough for me.
public int RecvSerialData(ref byte[] respBuf)
{
    var recvBuf = new byte[2048];
    var count = m_serial.BytesToRead;
    if (count > 0)
    {
        var offset = 0;
        m_serial.Read(recvBuf, offset, count);      
        offset += count;
        while(true)
        {
             count = m_serial.BytesToRead;
             if(count == 0)
             {
                 break;
             }
             m_serial.Read(recvBuf, offset, count);
             offset += count;
             Thread.Sleep(5);
        }

        // Do something with respBuf
        return offset;
    }
    return -1;
}

It would sleep 5ms or 10ms for most data, good enough for me.

while (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < delay) - do not implement a delay like that. It burns up your CPU. Use either Thread.Sleep or if you are async await Task.Delay.

Sidenote: "My project is a Winform project with .NET Framework 4.6." - why though? That's ancient. I'd recommend an upgrade.

You say you have a message protocol. In that case: do not use delays but actually implement that protocol. It doesn't matter if it is a ping-pong type one. Regard your input stream as exactly that: a constant stream of bytes. It's up to you to apply the protocol on it.

Yep, this is an ancient project that works on an ancient PC. So I'm trying to optimize it. I would upgrade the .NET Framework version if the ancient PC supports later.

Ok. But the version isn't really relevant to this specific problem, I just wanted to point out the fact. But if you are aware, then we can just accept that for the moment.

Okay, it seems that Thread.Sleep works. But the problem exists. The protocol is something like UDP which does not contain CRC or length of this message. I don't know the exact length of each message, it depends on their data body.

You don't necessarily need to know the length, if the protocol is using message delimiters. Does it? If it doesn't and has a dynamic message size, then it's a bad protocol. But maybe you can add other heuristics to your timeout. Like average message length / maximum message length ... what do you know about the protocol. Maybe add the corner stones to the question.

It says every message starts with 0x02. But it does not make sense since data body could contain 0x02 either.

Mhm, if it's "Ping-Pong" style, that also doesn't help for this problem. What you would need is some sort of "End-Of-Message" marker. 0x02 hints to the protocol using ASCII codes => 0x02 is "STX - Start of Text". Is there also 0x03 - "ETX - End of Text"? https://www.ascii-code.com/

Is this an XY problem? Please provide a specification document for the protocol you want to handle. It would be better to ask how to implement the program to achieve that.
